# Как отделить нужный текст от элемента списка

Tags: python, python-3.x

У меня есть список с элементами в нем типа "/view_profile?pet_id=15521478" , как отделить от всех элементов списка "/view_profile?pet_id=" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
lst = ["/view_profile?pet_id=34532234", "/view_profile?human_id=546476346"]
new = [tuple(i.split('=')) for i in lst]
# [('/view_profile?pet_id', '34532234'), ('/view_profile?human_id', '546476346')]
# либо генератор
new = (tuple(i.split('=')) for i in lst)
# и pet_id :)
new = [i.split('=')[1] for i in lst if 'pet_id' in i]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def e_split(elist, key='pet_id='):
    for e in elist:
        s = e.rsplit(key, 1)
        if len(s) == 2:
            yield s[1]
print(*e_split(["/view_profile?pet_id=15521478", "/view_profile?human_id=234"]))
```